# Stop date to epoch conversion in javascript

Tags: javascript, epoch, date-conversion

I have a code where I try to set date 20 days back from current date on server. I have used a variable(say ***dateRange***) in javascript to get current date. But on using the same variable second time for **setDate()** function value of ***dateRange*** is changed to epoch from date. I know I can convert epoch to date and proceed but is there a way to stop this automatic conversion.

```
var dateRange=new Date(currentDate);  
dateRange = dateRange.setDate(dateRange.getDate() - 20);
```

Comment: Are you confused about the return value of `setDate`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate#Return_value

Comment: *"...dateRange is changed to epoch from date..."* No, it isn't *changed*. `Date` objects are based on the epoch. Always.

Comment: You are manually overwriting your Date with the epoch time. Nothing else is changing it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Internally dates are stored as milliseconds from the epoch date.
To achieve what you are trying to do you can subtract the number of milliseconds that corresponds to 20 days:

```js
var currentDate = "2019-07-29T07:14:57.269Z";
var dateRange = new Date(currentDate);  

var pastDate = new Date(dateRange - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 20);

console.log('current', currentDate);
console.log('20 days ago', pastDate);
```

anyway if you are doing a lot of date/time manipulations in your app i suggest you to use this library: https://momentjs.com/

Comment: There is no reason `setDate` wouldn't work here. Working in milliseconds instead of using it is trying to apply a fix to something that is not broken.

Comment: sure, you can use also setDate, but if you read carefully the question you'll realize that the post creator was a bit confused about what's going on under the hood. My solution is more concise and uses only the bare minimun code to work

Comment: "Under the hood" `setDate` would work better as it removes the necessity of manual calculations. And if you suggest Moment.JS, then that's a call to move *away* from manual calculations and use the API in the Date library. Which is what `setDate` is.

Answer (score 0):

`setDate` modifies the date object, and returns the epoch value. Just don't save the epoch value in `dateRange`, so you can use the date object after modifying it:

```js
var currentDate = new Date();
var dateRange = new Date(+currentDate);
console.log(dateRange.toISOString());
dateRange.setDate(dateRange.getDate() - 20);
console.log(dateRange.toISOString());
```

---

Side note: Copying a date by doing `var dateRange = new Date(currentDate);` is/was unreliable on some browsers. In the above, I've changed it to `var dateRange = new Date(+currentDate);` (note the `+`, converting the date to its epoch value), which is reliable.